# Close a Window from Another In Wpf

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

If two Window is opened mainly A and B, how to close Window A using code that written on Window B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a property on Window B that you pass the creating Window to. Something like this. I have a Window named MainWindow and a second Window named Window2.

**Main Window**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Window2 secondForm;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            secondForm = new Window2();
            secondForm.setCreatingForm =this;
            secondForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Window2**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        Window creatingForm;

        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Window setCreatingForm
        {
            get { return creatingForm; }
            set { creatingForm = value; }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (creatingForm != null)
                creatingForm.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

---

In respose to your comment, closing a window that was created by another form is as easy as calling the Close Method of the created Form:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Window2 secondForm;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (secondForm == null)
            {
                secondForm = new Window2();
                secondForm.Show();
            }
            else
                secondForm.Activate();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (secondForm != null)
            {
                secondForm.Close();
                secondForm = new Window2();
                //How ever you are passing information to the secondWindow
                secondForm.Show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: :- Good Work. Actually i want to close Window2 from MainWindow. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @AnoopMohan Closing a form by the form that created it is a lot easier, you just just have to keep the reference to the created form and call the Close Method on it.

Comment: :- Thank you sir. . Now i can close the window. But i need to do one more thing.. I want to close the window and to open the same window with different value during the same event. Sorry for disturbing you. . Thanks in Advance. .

Comment: @AnoopMohan I changed the button2_click event to reopen the window, I am not sure what/how the value is that you are passing to the secondWindow so I can not get more specific than this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to close any window from any other window. You can modify it to work with multiple instances by giving your windows some unique identifier and then just searching for that in the foreach loop.

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void CloseWindowOfWhichThereIsOnlyOne<T>()
    {
        Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (w.GetType().Assembly == currentAssembly && w is T)
            {
                w.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or with a unique identifier "fudge":

```
    public static void CloseWIndowUsingIdentifier(string windowTag)
    {
        Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (w.GetType().Assembly == currentAssembly && w.Tag.Equals(windowTag))
            {
                w.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I like this better than the suggested solution because you don't need to mess with your windows, other than to give them unique tags. I've only been using this for small projects where there is no risk of things not being unique, I'm not going to lose track of 10-12 windows!

The other suggested solution is a little silly (I don't have 50 karma to comment on it) as you could just call win.close() if you already had a reference to the object...

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple make one public class and method like this

```
class Helper
{
 public static void CloseWindow(Window x)
    {
        Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      //  int count = Application.Current.Windows;
        foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            //Form f = Application.OpenForms[i];
            if (w.GetType().Assembly == currentAssembly && w==x)
            {
                w.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now call this function from where you want close window like this .

```
 Helper.CloseWindow(win);//win is object of window which you want to close.
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (w.Name != "Main_Window_wind" )
            {
                w.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
//name is the x:Name="Main_Window_wind" in xaml
```

You can close now as hiden all windows without closing the named Main_Window_wind , you can add another window to be not closed with this in if: w.Name != "Main_Window_wind" && w.Name != "AnyOther_Window_wind" &&...

a quicker way is this:

```
        for (int intCounter = App.Current.Windows.Count - 1; intCounter > -1; intCounter--)
        {

            if (App.Current.Windows[intCounter].Name != "Main_Window_wind")
                App.Current.Windows[intCounter].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem